# adding img in js

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript to create an image element like so:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
```

What would I do to give this img a width of 100%?

Comment: Bonus points for not using jQuery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

....

```
var img = document.createElement('img'); 
img.setAttribute('width', '100%');
```

Make sure that you attach the `img` to the `body`.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could either specify the width on that image: (taken from others' answer)

```
var img = document.createElement('img'); 
img.setAttribute('width', '100%');
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(img);
```

Or specify a class name and target it in CSS:

JavaScript:

```
var img = document.createElement('img'); 
img.setAttribute('class', 'wide');
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(img);
```

CSS:

```
img.wide {
    width:100%;
}
```